# close popup window with same button

Tags: android, popup

I want to close the popup window by the same button from which it opens, When I click that button again then popup window should be closed. and also want to clear that window when I click on back button. can anyone help me in this issue?
Thank you.

here is my code,

```
ivmainmenu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            LayoutInflater layoutInflater 
             = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()
              .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
            View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popupwindow, null);  
          final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                  LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);  
                popupWindow.showAsDropDown(ivmainmenu, 150,14);
                popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);

                TextView tvpopupwork = (TextView)popupView.findViewById(R.id.tvpopupwork);
                TextView tvpopupabout = (TextView)popupView.findViewById(R.id.tvpopupabout);
                TextView tvpopupservices = (TextView)popupView.findViewById(R.id.tvpopupservices);
                TextView tvpopupcontact = (TextView)popupView.findViewById(R.id.tvpopupcontact);

                tvpopupwork.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this,Ourwork.class);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

                tvpopupabout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this,Aboutus.class);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                        startActivity(intent);  
                    }
                });

                tvpopupservices.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this,Services.class);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

                tvpopupcontact.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this,Contact.class);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
           }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also create 2 listeners for listening on different events.
Listener 1 - this would be used to perform the task after opening the popup window
Listener 2 - to close the popup window

You can set the listener from another listener (switch the listener on button click).

```
listener2 = new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    tv.setText("Listener2");
    //assign button to listener1
    button.setOnClickListener(listener1);
}};

listener1 = new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    tv.setText("Listener1");
    //assign button to listener2
    button.setOnClickListener(listener2);
}};

//set this listener as the default(initially) listener onCreate
button.setOnClickListener(listener1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a boolean variable like;

```
boolean toggle = true;
```

and in onClickListener

```
PopupWindow popupWindow;
if(toggle){
   // Show popup here
   toggle = false;
}
else{
   if(popupWindow != null && popupWindow.isShowing())
      popupWindow.dismiss();
   toggle = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use a boolian flag

```
   if(flag)
{
hideWindow();
flag=false;
}
else
{
showWindow();
flag=true;
}
```

`Override` `onBackPressed()` to hide when back is pressed

Comment: where should i write this things?

Comment: this is not the full code to copy-paste.write First snippet on your on click of button and Override onBackpressed() anywhere in your activity.